# "Widget loading" after app update (path to widget provider changed)

Tags: android, widget

I had my widget provider on this path:

`com.arkadiusz.Provider.AppWidgetProvider`

After the update, I changed this path to

`com.arkadiusz.providers.AppWidgetProvider`

I found that this cause the "loading widget" problem when user update the app. Is there any solution to somehow tell the system that the location of provider has changed? I know that one solution would bo to leave it on the previuos location, but it does not mach my package naming convention in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to achieve that you want. *AppWidgetHost* just trying to get your widgets from *AppWidgetManager*, and *AppWidgetManager* trying to get previous widgets by *ComponentName*, so after changing package name of yours *AppWidgetProvider*, *AppWidgetHost* can't restore your previous widgets, cuz he got old ComponentName. That's why you can't achieve this.

P.S. Widget in Android so unpopular, that's why it has really bad api.